# Unable to download API Bundle google plugin app engine

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-api

When I go Add Google API's and click on any API I want to download I
get the following error
"There was a problem downloading the API bundles, See Error log for
more details" Can any one help me figure out what might be going wrong
and where is this logs location ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error Log can be accessed by clicking on Window - Error Log.

The server is currently malfunctioning and returning HTTP Error 502 (Bad Gateway). It should be a transient issue, though, and everything should be back to normal soon.

Comment: Thanks Claudio, The logs indeed say that its a 502. I hope it works soon:)

Comment: Is there any estimation on when this gets fixed ?

Comment: I just tested it and it worked,the issue should be officially over.